# Azure Data Factory failure to create Private Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, endpoint, azure-virtual-network

Update (added error message): [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr1Dt.jpg) I am trying to create a private endpoint for my dedicated pool. I went through and created an integrated runtime with a managed virtual network and when I attempt to create the private endpoint I am greeted with "failed to create private endpoint for client 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000, cluster 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:Id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, name=xxxxxxxx". I am not sure why... I have an endpoint connected to a database without issue and have connected to a dedicated pool in a dev-test environment.

Where I am building this dedicated pool, server, and ADF is all in a new subscription and all of those components are newly created as well. I have created a user for ADF in the dedicated pool with all of the necessary permissions. I don't know if it has something to do with permissions in the server/subscription but I am confused. I appreciate any thoughts that anyone may have. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer this document https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/azure-sql-database-to-adf-connectivity-using-azure-private/ba-p/3410956

Comment: Hey @AmareswarapuBhavani thanks for the link. I went through those steps again, but I think I have a slightly different issue. My network public access is set to "selected networks" and the ADF IP is added to that. I need an endpoint because every time I run a pipeline the IP changes, but when I created it I received an error message. I added an image of it to the original post, if you have any time I would really appreciate any additional thoughts you may have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario and it's working fine for me.

- **Networking setting for Dedicated SQL Pool server:**
  Selected **Public access** for `Selected Networks` and **Checked** the `Allow azure services and resource to access this server`.
  [image]
- Created **Azure integration runtime** with `Virtual network configuration` **Enabled**.
  [image]
- Created Managed private endpoint Dedicated SQL Pool server.[image]
- Approved private endpoints from Dedicated SQL Pool server network settings.
  [image]
- **Managed endpoint created succesfully**
  [image]

Comment: My understanding of checking the "Allow azure services and resource to access this server" button was that it would allow all azure services access and not be secure. Is that an incorrect way of thinking about it? We were able to solve this another way by creating a virtual network and private endpoint within the subscription instead of trying to do it all within ADF. Thank you.